# How to change default encoding in NetBeans 8.0

Tags: netbeans, encoding

I'm wondering if I can change default encoding in NetBeans 8.0... I searched a lot but I haven't find a way how to change the encoding in this version of NetBeans.

I have this tag in my html document:
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

BUT! As you can see on attached image, NetBeans notice is warning me about an encoding problem.

[image: Internal encoding declaration "utf-8" disagrees with the actual encoding of the document ("windows-1250")]

> Internal encoding declaration "utf-8" disagrees with the actual encoding of the document ("windows-1250").

I created index.html by "new file" function in NetBeans. There is UTF-8 encoding in project properties, so I think it should be UTF-8. I really don't know where that 'windows-1250' came from!!

Where I can find some option to change default encoding or even current file encoding in NetBeans 8.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change file encoding in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085940/3820049) given by [Danny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181218/danny)

> Navigate to `<Netbeans installation directory>/etc` and open the `netbeans.conf` file.
>
> Add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` at the end of the line that starts with `netbeans_default_options` (make sure to include the leading space).
>
> Restart Netbeans and it should be in UTF-8
>
> To verify go to `help -> about` and check System: `Windows Vista version 6.0 running on x86; UTF-8; nl_NL (nb)`

Comment: Thank you, Rex! It seems to be an answer. First I misunderstood this solution and I was searching this line of code... Then I see the word "add" and suddenly everything becomes clear :D Problem solved... thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly the encoding to UTF8.
I find netbeans.conf file on C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\etc Added at end of Line 46 your trick ;) : netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true **-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**"

Comment: The answer is slightly misleading: 'Netbeans home', it least to me, implies 'NetBeans user home' while the file is actually in the etc directory under the NetBeans installation directory

Comment: @Andrei LED: Thx for the feedback, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: Can't remember the exact reasoning since this was almost 7 years ago. But I think I though there was a distinct difference since the original question was about changing the encoding of _one_ file and this one is for the default encoding. The answer I'm referring to isn't an actual answer to the original question but rather to this one.

But I can of course see your point and won't argue against it, I simply wanted to explain my reasoning.

Answer (score 11):

Answer here worked well for me on Netbeans 7.3 [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034891/how-do-you-set-the-encoding-to-utf-8-in-netbeans-6-9)

Right click on the project name and click on properties. Sources tab -> Encoding and change it to whatever you need. In my case i needed Windows 1252 encoding.

Comment: This is a best answer because you probably only need a different encoding setting per project.

Comment: But it seems it does not change the encoding of existing files

Comment: I encounter an encoding problem with .properties file. I opened a properties dialog via context menu in Files for that file and set 'Use project encoding' option.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem with a cyrillic characters (russian and ukranian letters) in netbeans 8.1 for Ubuntu 14.04. I have fixed problem like @Rex Wagenius adviced + I had to change a font of netbeans (in main menu: Tools  -> Option -> Fonts&Colors -> Syntax tab -> Font changed from Courier to Serif 20). Hope this answer will be helpful for some users with the same problem.

Comment: I was using Liberation Mono. Changing to DejaVu Sans Mono fixed my problem. If anyone reading this is having trouble displaying UTF8 characters, try changing the IDE font to something else