# Netbeans does not decode special characters

Tags: java, html, netbeans, encoding, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a HTML file using Jsoup. In this HTML there is a special character that I want to remove, (€), this is how it's originally:

```
<span class="price-value">
    49,99 €
</span>
```

However, Netbeans shows this when printing that element:

```
49.99 ?
```

Therefore, I cannot do this:

```
price.replace( "€", "" ).replace( ",", "." ).trim();
```

Neither this:

```
price.replace( "\\?", "" ).replace( ",", "." ).trim();
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: do you use encoding of utf-8?

Comment: You should take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Netbeans shows this when printing that element

Almost certainly this is because your NetBeans console hasn't been configured to support Unicode chars, which is why you've been misled. For a solution to that, see: [How to change default encoding in NetBeans 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778725/how-to-change-default-encoding-in-netbeans-8-0)

So, the document is fine, the regular expressions would have worked, and there's no need to change anything else.

Here's a minimal working example of the original document getting parsed correctly, the Euro symbol replaced, and `49.99` returned.

```
Element doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><span class=\"price-value\">49,99 €</span></body></html>");
Element span = doc.select("span").get(0);
System.out.println( span.text().replace("€", "").replace(",", ".").trim() );
```

Comment: It's weird, because It has always been working until now. I've reinstalled Netbeans and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10894226/6083675):

> To match individual characters, you can simply include them in an a character class, either as literals or via the `\u20AC` syntax

The unicode for the Euro is `\u20AC`.

---

Note: I'm not sure why it would be displayed as a `?`, but that might be just because it's not ASCII, and might be missing in the font.

Answer (score 0):

Use this ->

```
<span class="price-value">
49,99 &euro;
</span>
```

It is the representation of € sign in HTML