# Wrong file encoding of html5 file (written in NetBeans)

Tags: html, apache, netbeans

I have a php file that is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

The php file is in a local Apache linux server.

The html generated with the php file starts with 
`<!DOCTYPE html>` and has `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside the `<head>` section.

In the root directory of the server there is a `.htaccess` file with `AddCharset UTF-8 .php` on it.

In the `/etc/apache2/conf-available/charset.conf` the line `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` is uncommented. I did `sudo service apache2 restart` after the modification of `charset.conf` and after creating the `.htaccess` file.

The browser still shows the wrong character set. In the text editor there is the word `diámetro`, Chrome 55 shows `diÃ¡metro`.

What else should I try?

Greetings from Paraguay.

Comment: you need to save the html file itself as a UTF-8 in your text editor then. Which text editor? I recommend [Notpad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (it's free)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is your text editor file is not being saved as a proper UTF-8, and so regardless of what the *contents* of that file says (html5 meta tag) it's still not going to magically turn into UTF-8, if it's not saved as a UTF-8.

Comment: The file is already encoded with UTF-8. I use Netbeans.

Comment: I uploaded the file in [link](https://www.a1ci.com/articulos/varillas.php).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the file (`varillas.php`) and it has the correct HTTP headers as well as the correct HTML5 meta header. But looking at the source code myself, I see what is displayed on the page (`diÃ¡` etc) so the issue is -I still think- your NetBeans *saving* the file. Save the file in netbeans with `Save As` and be sure to select the correct UTF-8 charset.

Comment: I've updated my answer, with possible solutions and what I believe the problem is. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: err, I've just read your comment above re: UTF-8, how do you know the file is encoded with UTF-8? My Netbeans (8.1) I can find no info at all about what the file encoding actually is

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is actually a pretty interesting issue, and from comments with the OP, and viewing the file itself online; the issue is not with the server, or the HTTP headers which, correctly set as UTF-8.

HTTP HEADER

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTML5 HEAD

> `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Looking at the source code of this file the issue appears more and more to be that the program used to write the file (`NetBeans`) is not saving it with a correct UTF-8 file encoding.

Because the source file is NOT UTF-8, it means any references to HTTP headers or HTML5 Head tags stating to use UTF-8 will not work, because they're trying to convert milk to wine, which you can only do if you start with wine [or at least, grapes]!

So; with some research I've found to my surprise that (as of NetBeans 8.1 / windows 10) you *can't* set the character set of a code file, Netbeans can set the *project* character set, but that's a little tricky. There is [a guide this this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans) (See the answer by Danny) (and another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778725/how-to-change-default-encoding-in-netbeans-8-0)) about how to do this.

There is also a video guide to the above solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D35quN4VHUI).

Also see some NetBeans [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258590) [reports](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=157498), some of which are *6 years old* and a far from ideal situation... It appears NetBeans uses your OS default character encoding, such as usually Windows-1252 or similar. These can be less compatible with internet standard encodings (such as UTF-8), as I think you're finding here.

So I can only really say that if this was my choice, I would  stop using NetBeans, and move over to something more reliable such as [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

You can open the offending file (`varillas.php`) in another program (NotePad++) and check the characters displayed on the page are the correct ones (`diámetro` rather than `diÃ¡metro`) and then **Save As** a UTF-8 encoded file, then reupload the file and *Hard* refresh your browser (to clear the browser cache) and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: The file is UTF-8, I did verify the encoding in notepadqq in linux and notepadd++ in windows. I uploaded the php file and echo the contents without the html headers and it shows the characters correctly.

Comment: Ah ok, it seems odd that the HTML5 head meta tag doesn't seem to work but glad you got it solved `:)`

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the file has a Byte Order Mark which can cause issues, [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6080299/3536236), but the HTML5 meta header in itself shouldn't be an issue. I wonder if somehow its conflicting with the `es` declaration in the HTML tag?

Comment: I already tested with `<html>` without `lang="es"` with same result.

Answer (score 0):

There was a `utf8_encode` command in the code that I was missing and was the culprit.
Thank you for your answers.

[`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) was used because the HTML body was previously loaded from an ISO-8859-1 source. Then I modified the code to load from UTF-8 source and forgot to delete.

Comment: Glad you found it, could you elaborate a bit more on the `utf8_encode`? I don't recognise it. If it's the PHP function, I'm having trouble seeing where it would fit in the work flow....