# Entry name with japanese character becomes '??????' in an archive, when updated using truezip

Tags: java, archive, php-ziparchive, truezip

I am using truezip 7.7.9 package to do crud operations on archive files. When I add a file with japanese characters the entry becomes '???????' after the second updation of the archive.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add a file in the archive with entry name in japanese(日本語テーブル)
2. unmount() the archive.
3. Add another file in the archive and unmount again. now the previous enty becomes '?????' if we list the archive entries.

```java
TFile archive = new TFile(zipFilePath);
File entry = new TFile(zipFilePath+"日本語テーブル.txt");
Writer writer = new TFileWriter(entry);
archive.umount()
```

I could not find anything in the documentation related to this.

Comment: well, for me different occurrence. But, when i was creating jar file and zipping it the same thing happens. The reason was encoding. I ware using utf-16 , i change it to utf-8

Comment: how can I change the encoding setting @parladneupane

Comment: Are you using IDE's or you can set the encoding and decoding before and after pars.

Comment: I am using netbeans @parladneupane

Comment: I have not used Netbeans, but there must be code encoder there. found it , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778725/how-to-change-default-encoding-in-netbeans-8-0

Comment: did you use -Dfile.encoding system property or some other way? @parladneupane

Comment: nop, in eclipse there is a section called code in preference with UI. I changed from there

Comment: IF not share your code with us, we need code for forther analysis

Comment: @parladneupane I use utf8 still face the issue. will share the code

Comment: @parladneupane Added the code snippet

Comment: Is this the error you got , error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII, add error log also

Comment: @parladneupane I didn't get any error. It's just that the archive entry is malformed.