# Netbeans C++ return type of templated functions

Tags: c++, netbeans

For some reason the code completion in netbeans can't figure out the return type of templated functions.  Take the following example...

```
struct Test
{
   int val;
};

int main()
{
     vector<Test> v;
     Test t = {10};
     v.push_back(t);
     cout << v[0].val;  //Netbeans gives the warning "Unable to resolve identifier val"
     return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine but what is annoying is that I get this error all over my code when I use vectors.  Also the code completion does not seem to work.  When I type v[0]. there is no drop down giving me to option to choose val.

I am using netbeans 7.4 along with 64bit MinGW.

Comment: @Avanz the points are deducted immediately when you create the bounty so the OP had the 200+ rep when they created it.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions listed below (and what were the results)? Especially the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful

Answer (score 5):

Well there seems to bug in the Netbeans 7.2 version and later it was fixed.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=172227

You can find the complete discussion and possible resolution on the same problem from the following link. Here you can find how to resolve this problem(possibly).

[Netbeans 7.2 shows "Unable to resolve identifier" , although build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful)

Answer (score 1):

Follow some simple steps to get your identifiers resolved, given on the following link 
[Netbeans 7.2 shows "Unable to resolve identifier" , although build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful)1

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
struct Test
{
   int val;
};
```

with

```
typedef struct
{
    int val;
} Test;
```

in pure C "Test" would not be a defined type but "struct Test" would be.  By changing to a typedef then you then have "Test" as a defined type.