# Erroneous "Unable to resolve identifier" in Netbeans

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, netbeans-8

My program compiles fine, but Netbeans tells me "Unable to resolve identifier to_string."

I tried everything in "[Netbeans 7.2 shows "Unable to resolve identifier" , although build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful)" and I set the "C++ standard" to "C++11" in the code assistance options.

This is the only function giving this problem so far. It is however also the first C++11 feature I am using, which leads me to believe it has something to do with Netbeans not understanding that I am using C++11, although I specify it explicitly in the code assistance menu.

Minimal example:

```
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::to_string(1);
}
```

EDIT: the same problem arises where using `nullptr`

EDIT2: I suddenly realized it might be important to mention that I do not use a generated Makefile, but SCons.

Comment: I would make sure it's a c++11 related issue by using something that's a newer language keyword, for example `int* testCpp11 = nullptr` and see if you still get problems.

Comment: @shuttle87 `nullptr` is also marked with "unable to resolve identifer"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this question is seven months old but since it came up as the second result to a google search I'll tell the answer I came up with.  For Netbeans at least.  Go to your project properties and make sure you have you "C Compiler"->"C Standard" set to C11, and your "C++ compiler"->"C++ Standard" set to C++11.  You have to set BOTH or it will still give false errors!

Comment: Just encountered the issue again with nullptr, tried your solution and it gives the correct highlighting now, so this seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: Don't know how you found this but you saved me from going nuts :)

Comment: @Oebele This fixed my issue. I had TWO (!) different projects in Netbeans. In one I had both C++ compiler and C Compiler with C++11 and C11 respectively. In the other project I had both of them to the default. But I had the issue in the later (with the default compilers). When I changed the compilers for the first project, it immediately fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: This issue still exists in 8.2 on both Linux and Windows, even though the default (under Tools) is set up correctly.  It's a little annoying that this has to be setup per project, but it seems to work even with c14 (not tried c17).

Comment: Yep.  Still the same in NB 10.  Wasted hours on that until I found this thread.

Comment: Another wrinkle to add to this solution:  most of the files in my project had a C++ level set on the individually.  I have no idea why, as I'm the only project user and I never did it.  The solution was to open the xml project file and find all instances of the attribute "flavor2" on all the <item> nodes and set them all to "0".  a quick regex search and replace, save and ta-da, problem fixed.

Answer (score 6):

This will solve the problem:

1. Right click on "**Project**".
2. Select "**Code Assistance**".
3. Clean C/C++ cache.
4. Restart IDE.

Comment: This worked for me!  I tried setting the compilers for C and C++ to v11, but it didn't work even after restarting Netbeans.  But clearing the cache worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete and sometimes even syntax highlighting are always faulty with C++. The more you go in depth with C++ and C++11, the more Eclipse and Netbeans will start underlining everything with a red wavy line. Some of my (correct and perfectly compiling) programs are a huge red wavy line. I suggest you disable error markers altogether and you keep autocomplete, but in many cases it just won't work and you have to make the best of it.

Comment: Disabling features that don't work is not exactlly a solution is it?, what's the point of using an IDE full of helpful features to end up disabling, you should recommend then using a text editor instead of an IDE.

Comment: I agree it isn't a solution. But it is an answer because the reality is: Netbeans IDE just can't cope with all these complex abstractions. If this is not what you want, A different IDE/Application than Netbeans would be better suited.

(I don't really know any much better ones though)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation. This was occurred because I used .c file instead of .cpp

Answer (score 0):

for Netbeans 8.2 (on Linux) only the following worked for me: Tools -> Options -> Code Assistance -> Macro Definitions: 
change:`__cplusplus=199711L`
to:`__cplusplus=201402L`
for C++14
or to `__cplusplus=201103L`
for C++11

Answer (score 0):

I did all the above but what did the trick for me was recognizing that the Makefile had g++ rather than g++ -std=c++11.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve c++17 related 'Unable to resolve identifier' in  latest netbeans 8.2 or 9 version,  one may  need to set the macro definition __cplusplus=201703L as the default C++14 standard macro definition unable to resolve those unexpected error messages appeared in the editor.