# Vector size() marked as error by NetBeans: Unable to resolve Identifier

Tags: c++, vector, netbeans

So I am working with some multidimensional vectors in C++ in NetBeans, and whenever I try to call the `.size()` method, NetBeans marks it in red and says "Unable to resolve identifier size.". However, it does recognise other vector methods such as `.push_back()`. The code compiles well though...

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> int1D;
typedef vector<int1D> int2D;

int2D populate (int2D arg1, int arg2);

int main () {
    //Do stuff...
}

int2D populate (int2D grid, int gridSize) {
    int2D my_2d_array;
    //Here I fill my_2d_array...
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSize; y++) {
            int value = grid[x][y];
            if (value == 0) {
                //get all coordinaes of values with 0
                int1D coordinates;
                coordinates.push_back(x);
                coordinates.push_back(y);
                my_2d_array.push_back(coordinates);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < my_2d_array.size(); x++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error highlighting:

[image]

Comment: Is this an IDE generated error or a compiler error?

Comment: No, it compiles fine...

Comment: NetBeans is a pretty crappy C++ IDE.

Comment: Just seems like the same problem with Intellisense. You could try deleting your user file or closing+reopening your IDE but it's otherwise nothing to worry about. I'm not sure if there's a fix though

Comment: I gave up on netbeans, its c++ code completion and analysis is pretty poor, visual studio code is better

Comment: @AlanBirtles I do find NetBeans' customisability to be a lot more flexible than that of VS, but anyways, I'm running Linux...

Comment: Visual studio code works perfectly on Linux

Comment: @Tas how do I delete the user file? what is it/where is it located?

Comment: try to reinstall C++ plugin . But my bet is nothing would help netbeans there

Comment: Too many NetBeans haters here... Try to go to `Project Properties`, find `Code Assistance` and click `Reparse Project`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Reparse Project" did not seem to do anything for me. The accepted answer from [Rafayel Paremuzyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54683833/3389183) *seemed* to work initially but the errors returned. Instead, I found that the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35025731/3389183 worked. The process is straightforward:

1. Right click on the project and select Properties.
2. Look at Code Assistance. Make sure C++ Compiler has "C++ Standard" set to "C++11" (or "C++14") and not just "Default". It may be necessary to do the same with "C Standard" for the C Compiler under Code Assistance.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same symptoms, i.e. I had a vector defined, and
it gave same error message "Unable to resolve identifier size",
while it compiled succesfully.

Doing following helped:

Right click on the project->"Code Assistance" -> "Clean C/C++ cache and restart IDE"

Note: this is different from "RightClick on project"->"Code Assistance" ->"Reparse Project", which mentioned in several posts, but didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ default standard needs to be changed to C++ 11, rather than default, which is from the previous answer.  I'm somewhat doubtful that any actual relatively up to date C++ standard leaves these functions out of the definition, but I can't say for certain, and I'm not sure what standard they are referring to as "default".

That's just stupid.  Netbeans seems to require a lot of coddling and fiddling just to make it build code that works great pretty much everywhere.  I haven't had issues like these since about 2000