# Eclipse to_string() not resolved/declared

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, tostring

I have Eclipse installed on three Windows 7 systems, and one Linux machine. I got this in my code:

```
#include <string>
using std::to_string();
```

All except one system with Win7 has to_string() not resolved/declared.  I have tried following suggestions from many pages including:

[Turn off eclipse errors (that arent really errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131939/turn-off-eclipse-errors-that-arent-really-errors)

None works.  Even copying the entire eclipse folder does not help. I cant believe how they let this error persist.  Any idea to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Eclipse CDT doesn't come with a compiler. You need to install one separately, e.g. Mingw32. And the syntax is `using std::to_string;`

Comment: You can try `itoa`, almost same as `to_string`

Comment: @Ali There is no such function as itoa() in C++.

Comment: To OP - you need a modern C++ compiler. And Eclipse is really a very poor C++ IDE.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, Eclipse promised multi-platform capacity.  I am trying to move away from Windows, and thought it would be good for the transition.  Seems like NetBeans will be a good friend.

Comment: Since `std::to_string()` is a function from the C++11 standard library, it not being resolved is usually a sign of the project not being correctly configured for C++11 support. That's a common problem; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support).

Comment: Chief, I tried configuring Eclipse times and times again.  It only frustrates me.  I am not the only one plagued with it.  There seems to be no permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hate.  The solution came from unexpected places.

1. For my Linux system, I decided to install NetBeans 8.2 in frustration.  The code with to_string() unresolved was copied over and tried to compiled.  To my horror, to_string() was still not resolved, and the variable names came up unresolved.

   a. So I followed this fix first (for NetBeans 8.2, go with Run>Set
   Project Configuration>Customize..>C++ Compiler>General>Include
   Directories):
   [Netbeans 7.2 shows "Unable to resolve identifier" , although build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful)

   b. Then, I needed to switch the C compiler to C11.  For NetBeans 8.2, go with Run>Set Project Configuration>Customize..>C Compiler>Build>C Compiler>General>C Standard --> set to C11.

   c. Lastly, I needed to switch the C compiler to C++11.  For NetBeans 8.2, go with Run>Set Project Configuration>Customize..>C++ Compiler>Build>C Compiler>General>C Standard --> set to C++11.

   Next, I did a 'Clean & Build Project.'  The text editor still complained about not able to resolve 'string identifier'.  However, the code built, and ran just fine.  Afterwards, I went back to Eclipse out of curiosity.  Lo and behold, to_string() was no longer an error.  Something must have happened when I changed the settings with NetBeans, and solved the problem in Eclipse.
2. On another Windows 7 previously freshly installed, I tried to compiled the same code with Eclipse.  It did not build, as 'make' was missing.  I used the Cygwin installer file to get that package, as well as the missing GCC packages.  Everything built, and to_string() resolved.  This seemed to suggest the problem was with the Cygwin installation on which Eclipse ran.

All things considered, Eclipse freaking sucks!  @Neil Butterworth, I picked Eclipse trying to move away from Visual Studio and the Windows ecosystem.  Eclipse promised multi-platform capability, which I thought would help with the transition.  This to_string() problem's persistence, and multiple failed efforts to point to a C++11 standard make a very strong point.  Eclipse can be a huge pain.

Comment: OK, the joy for Eclipse on Linux was short-lived.  to_string() error comes back again.