# my computer won't accept s.length, but other compilers do

Tags: c++, string, function, netbeans, netbeans-8

Playing with some functions and my computer/NetBeans cannot seem to run my code, even though it can be run in different compilers. Here's my function (keep in mind this isn't my whole project I do have an int main()):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
void convert (string& s){ //Creating a function that makes a variable lower case
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){ 
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]); //tolower lets me change to lower case
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is: "cannot resolve identifier length". if you need to see my whole project please ask, I don't mind, just think its a waste of time if it doesn't matter. I'm using NetBeans 8.2, thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you make a program with **only** that function and an empty `int main() {}`?

Comment: What compiler is it?

Comment: What happens if *explicitly* using `std::string` as the type?

Comment: Try looking this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful

Comment: @Galik Nothing changes.

Comment: @RetiredNinja NetBeans 8.2 and MinGW

Comment: @user2864740 I'm sorry i'm new at this, how would i do that?

Comment: @AakashDeep That worked, but now it's building fine, but cant run. It's saying: "RUN FAILED (exit value -1, 073, 741, 511, total time: 69ms)"

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @AidanChristopher Try searching this error in stackoverflow, you may find something.

Comment: @CraigYoung he _did_ provide a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Do you know about accepting an answer?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Are you claiming all the includes are _required_ to reproduce the problem? If not, then it's blatantly obviously ***not minimal***. By OP's own admission the code presented lacks `main`; hence it's ***not complete***. I cannot confirm it's verifiability; that _might_ need even ***more*** information such as how the compiler is actually called. MCVE is not a bunch of arbitrary letters meaning a little bit of code. Follow the link above to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `size()` instead of `length()` . For `string` in C++ there's no notable difference between them but `size()` is used in other STL containers like `map`, `vector` etc. too. So generally, people use `size()` function.

Usage is same like length(), `i < s.size()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the implementation of std::string has omitted the function length(); BTW, it does not return int, so you should get a warning ticket for that.  In future, please post a complete program, including main().

Workaround the old way;

```
#include <string>

void convert(std::string& s) { //Creating a function that makes a variable lower case
    const size_t sz = s.size();

    for (size_t i = 0; i<sz; ++i) {
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]); //tolower lets me change to lower case
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s("AbCdEf");
    convert(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Newfangled way...

```
#include <string>

void convert(std::string& s) { //Creating a function that makes a variable lower case
    for (char &ch : s) {
        ch = tolower(ch); //tolower lets me change to lower case
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s("AbCdEf");
    convert(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Even newfangleder way...

```
#include <algorithm>

void convert(std::string& s) { //Creating a function that makes a variable lower case
       std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::begin(s), ::tolower);
}
```