# Multiple types of bulleted list in sublists in beamer

Tags: latex, beamer

I tried to create a different bullets for sublists in beamer but everytime it creates the same bullet for nested lists as shown below. I tried `label=\roman*` but it is for enumitem. How do I change sublits bullets to something like arrow or rectangle?

[image]

Comment: unrelated to your question: I would use `--` to get a dash instead of a hyphen between "underfit' and "high"

Answer (score 2):

Beamer allows to set the template for each itemisation level separately. Changing the second level symbol works like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\rightarrow$}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
  \item test
    \begin{itemize}
    \item test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

(`itemize item` would be the top level symbols and `itemize subsubitem` would be the third level symbol)

P.S. you can also change the symbols on a case-by-case basis:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
    \begin{itemize}
    \item test
    \item[$\rightarrow$] test
    \item test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```