# Pound symbol in dynamically generated title tag

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, content-type, symbols

I am having trouble getting the £ symbol to render properly in a title tag.

I have tried using £ which comes out as a ? in a diamond. I have also tried:

```
&pound;
```

but that comes out as is.

I have also tried setting:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Before the output is echoed.

Here is how I am generating the content for the title tag:

```
public function marginAttribution($enquiryId)
  {

    $data = $this->model->marginAttribution($enquiryId) ;

    $output = '';
    $output .= 'Sales value (parts): '.$data['sellingCurrency'].number_format($data['sellingValueNative'], 2, '.', ',')."\n";
    $output .= 'Sales value (fees): '.$data['sellingCurrency'].number_format($data['sellingFees'], 2, '.', ',')."\n";
    $output .= 'Sales value total ('.$data['sellingCurrency'].'): '.$data['sellingCurrency'].number_format($data['sellingFees']+$data['sellingValueNative'], 2, '.', ',')."\n";
    $output .= "Sales value total (&pound;): £".number_format(($data['sellingFees']+$data['sellingValueNative'])/$data['sellingCurrencyRate'], 2, '.', ',')."\n";
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo $output;
  }
```

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze My database is set to utf-8, the page encoding is also set with the html5 version of the tag and I have tried splashing the header() function all over the scripts involved. No luck still.

Comment: Are your files *actually encoded* in UTF-8?

Comment: @deceze How do I check that in NetBeans?

Comment: No idea, check the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to edit the Netbeans config file as discussed in the answer in this post:

[How to change file encoding in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans)

Which solved my problem.