# Netbeans file cannot be safely opened

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I get files from friend who don't use netbeans IDE, when i open file that contain special caracter like 'é','à',... it show me this popup message :  [image: this popup message]

if i say yes it open the file and changes those caracters to '�' like [image: this] or [image: this]

Any idea how to open the file safely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letters you are mentioning seem to be French. You need to open the file, specifying the original encoding, then save the file as UTF-8

Comment: if i open the file, the code will be broken as mentioned, all special caracters will change by '�'. also if i open the file with notpad++, the encoding is utf8(without BOM)

Comment: When opening the file, you need to specify the code page. Probably 863 for french. Use another program such as notepad++. Once you successfuly open the file with all characters appearing correctly, save as UTF-8

Comment: yes it's working, but there is no internal solution for netbeans?

Comment: Frankly, I do not know. Maybe with a plugin. Anyway,  you are better off transforming all your code to UTF-8 and do away with code pages once and for all.

Comment: I already tried using Notepad++ to ensure that the encoding was UTF-8. I also tried changing to UTF-8-BOM. Neither fixed it in Netbeans.

Comment: @Ryan You first have to open your file specifying the correct code page. Once you see the characters correctly, save as UTF8.

Comment: No matter what I did with encodings (including editing the file in Notepad++ in various encodings), nothing helped. Eventually, what I did was manually remove all the special UTF-8 characters from the file and save it. Then, I re-added those characters and saved it. And Netbeans handled it fine.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered a very similar problem (I have some javascript files in Chinese which translated into similar non-human readable text upon re-opening the file in NetBeans).

My OS: Linux Mint (version 17, Cinnamon; Notepad++ not available and gedit did not solve the problem).

Netbeans Version: 8.0.1

However, I was blessed to have found the history feature! I was able to get a former version of my file restored and **backed it up immediately**.

To access a file's history simply **click on the History button** found on the left side of the tool bar between the tabs of open files at the top of the IDE and the actual source code. (You can also **right click on the file name** and selected **History -> Show History**). Then **Double click on a *Timestamp representing a valid version of your file.** Just below the table of Timestamps the old 'backup' file and the current 'corrupted' file should appear side-by-side. (You can preview several historical versions of the file until you find one that works best for you; of course, when choosing a file I suggest one which is still usable and has the most current Timestamp associated with it!) ). **Right click again on the 'backup' version of your choice -> Revert from History.** Click back on the Source button found right next to the History button.

Finally, to change the default encoding, I applied the fix suggested by Sebas and Danny here:
[How to change file encoding in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans)
Please note that the path to the netbeans.conf file is different (at least with version 8.0.1 on my Linux machine). The path on my machine was : **~/netbeans-8.0.1/etc/netbeans.conf.**

This saved the day for me and I hope it helps someone else out there! Bonne chance.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning how to specify the default encoding in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Found a netbeans solution online that works for MPLAB X.
Correction two files,
...\mplab_ide\etc\mplab_ide.conf
...mplab_ide\harness\etc\app.conf

in the line default_options= add an additional option "-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8".
Example
default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -J-Dstatistics.connect=false -J-Dcore.properties.disableHttpProxy=true ...
default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -J-Dcrownking.stream.verbosity=very-quiet ...