# how to fix netbeans Arabic encoding appearing as symbols

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, encoding

in netbeans the Arabic characters looks as strange symbols how can i set the encoding to 
 
solve this problem 
`OS : Linux Ubuntu 

netbeans version : 7.4`

image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsFk2.png

Comment: 7.4 shows arabic letters just fine for me. It could be an issue with the operating system instead. Here's a post about changing the encoding anyway: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans

Comment: it can't be the os i can use it to type تجربة

Comment: the project encoding wasn't wrong

Comment: It might seems so obvious but, did you try changing the font for something else? Courier new for example?

Comment: it was the font thanks for your help