# read from console an array with special characters

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] character = keyboard.next().toCharArray();
while (character.length != 5) {
     keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     character = keyboard.next().toCharArray();
}
```

Until you introduce 5 character keeps asking you to introduce the 5 characters again but when i try to introduce the special characters 'ñ' or 'ç' it doesn't work, i have tried it without the while to print the results and the only thing that prints are squares . How could this be solved?

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.4.

By it doesn't work I mean I just keep asking to introduce more characters and it is just stuck until you introduce 5 normal characters.

Comment: Looks like your console doesn't support non ASCII characters. Which environment are you using to execute your Java application?

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't work_?

Comment: Whats your IDE ? Eclipse ? Netbean ?

Comment: @ortis, why does that matter?

Comment: Cant explain how to configure the Console encoding without knowing the IDE

Comment: @ortis any decent IDE like those you mentioned won't have this problem. Surely the code is executed through command line or another kind of console or a very old OS.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Unless you hardcode special character (wich will set the encoding on UTF8 by default) you will get some *square* when trying to output in the console. There is countless issue on SO about people reading a file with special char and getting weird symbol instead.

Comment: @ortis I know but that's for Chinese, Japanese and Arabic characters. Using Spanish character `ñ` is not a common issue in console apps.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Yes it is :) I just tried it on Eclipse and got *Ã±*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza not all extended ASCII character sets have a codepoint for ñ

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc well, seems like I didn't know about them :)

Answer (score 1):

Use in both cases the encoding of your operating system.

```
String encoding = "Cp1252"; // Western Latin-1
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in, encoding); // Twice!
```

If you print the default encoding:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

You will probably see, that the IDE uses "UTF-8" or so. That is, it has changed `file.encoding`.
System.in and System.out however need to use just the original encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans) answer.

Edit the *netbeans.conf* in the *etc* folder of NetBean and add `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to `netbeans_default_options`. Then restart.