# HTML lang UTF-8 - cant see characters well

Tags: html, utf-8, lang

I have this website: [www.agroagro.com](http://www.agroagro.com)

And I put HTML:

```
<html lang="sr">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

but again I cant see properly characters: `č,ž,š,đ` and similar...

Why what is the problem?

Comment: Which is the encoding of the document?

Comment: When you save a text document, you choose an [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, ANSI, ... In this case you tell the browser to parse the text as if it were encoded in UTF-8, but clearly you used another encoding.

Comment: I use netbeans, and when I save documents nothing ask me

Comment: See [How to change file encoding in NetBeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4133195/1529630)

Comment: I see this but everything is ok with my encoding properies in netbeans, also in dreamweaver too