# How to open file in UTF-8 format in Netbeans; without distorting characters?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, utf-8

There are Norwegian characters in properties file. 
When i open in UTF-8 enabled Notepad++ it appears correctly:

```
Foreslåtte
```

But when i open same file in my Netbeans editor; it shows distorted characters like :

```
ForeslÃ¥tte
```

Netbeans Version in Use: 8.0.2.

Project Type: Maven Project

In Maven Proeject properties there is setting for UTF-8:

```
<properties>
    <app.navn>posten</app.navn>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <wro4j.version>1.7.6</wro4j.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding> <--
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
</properties>
```

Could anyone help in finding what settings need to be done in Netbeans to get correct UTF-8 characters?

Comment: I don't know netbeans specifically, but there are two possibilities here. 1 is that the file isn't actually encoded in UTF-8, or two, Netbeans is using your "platform default" encoding, which isn't UTF-8 for some reason.  Have you validated that it actually is a valid UTF-8 file?

Comment: @Daniel 
How to validate that? It is simple properties file having values in Key Value format; which contains Norwegian characters. It is getting opening in Notepad++ perfectly. How can i make Netbeans not to use platform default encoding any settings?

Comment: Like I said I don't know netbeans.  Notepad++ may not be loading it as UTF-8, it may have detected some other encoding.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans

Comment: If it's in a java file we can do that but for files like txt,properties it id diffiocult i guess

Comment: @Daniel:
I have already done few settings in Notepad++. That are to go into Settings -> Preferences -> New Document -> UTF-8 Selected. After these settings are done; when i edit properties file in Notepad++, it by default opens with proper Norwegian characters. Otherwise if i remove those settings then it picks default "Encoding in ANSI" and damage characters.

Comment: @Ajan
Thanks. Will try that. System restart is required for that as Netbeans is already opened and i am not allowed to do changes in file.

Comment: @Madhan
How can we do it for Java files? The settings must be same for both i think as it will reflect in netbeans project?

Comment: @fatherazrael Go to Project Properties-Sources Category Tab->change Encoding from UTF-8 to windows 1252

Comment: @Madhan
It does not work

Comment: @Ajan
I have done changes to .conf file as suggested in your link and it does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right Click Properties File -> Properties -> Encoding -> Tick Use Project Encoding

Now open the file and matter resolved.

**Note**: My Project Encoding was already set to UTF-8. You can set i: Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Select Encoding UTF-8

Comment: Is there a way to force this for all properties files in a project?

Answer (score 2):

If you open netbeans folder, edit the *netbeans.conf* (It's inside the *etc* folder), you might need to open the editor with administrator rights first.
Add  `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to the *netbeans_default_options*.
Restart netbeans, and it's now opening them correctly.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I often open files in NB that isn't in any project. I have struggled with this, searched in menus etc. But this works.

Answer (score 1):

> **Before Java 9**, the encoding of a .properties file is ISO-8859-1, also known as **Latin-1**. All non-ASCII characters must be entered by using Unicode escape characters, e.g. \uHHHH where HHHH is a hexadecimal index of the character in the Unicode character set.

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Further read : https://www.google.com/search?q=java+properties+ascii