# Why is my JSON file not saved in UTF-8 after editing?

Tags: json, utf-8, netbeans-8

How can edit a .json file with all special characters and save it in UTF-8 in an automatic way. (.properties files and similar)

I've tried ([How to open file in UTF-8 format in Netbeans; without distorting characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994279/how-to-open-file-in-utf-8-format-in-netbeans-without-distorting-characters), [How to change file encoding in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans))

- `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` In default options but that isn't working to me
- Open this file with gedit notepad and others and save it with encode utf8
- Right click > Properties > Sources > encode: utf8

Note: My project is already configured with UTF8 by default.

File editing

```
{
    "LOGIN": "Iniciar sesión",
    "PASSWORD": "Contraseña",
    "RECOVER_PASSWORD": "Recuperar contraseña",
    "PASSWORD_OR_EMAIL_INCORRECT": "Contraseña o correo electrónico incorrectos"
}
```

Saved file

```
{
    "LOGIN": "Iniciar sesi\u00f3n",
    "PASSWORD": "Contrase\u00f1a",
    "RECOVER_PASSWORD": "Recuperar contrase\u00f1a",
    "PASSWORD_OR_EMAIL_INCORRECT": "Contrase\u00f1a o correo electr\u00f3nico incorrectos"
}
```