# Problem with special characters in javascript function

Tags: jsp

I've got this html file

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="changeText()">
            Change!
        </button>

        <p id='change'>Camión</p> <!-- It's OK-->


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="jscaracteres.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this javascript function in "jscaracteres.js"

```js
function changeText() {
    var newText = "Camión 2.0"; //CamiÃ³n 2.0
    $("#change").html(newText); 
}
```

If I put the function inside html, there aren't any problem with special characters, but if I have the function changeText() in a .js file when I click the button, the text change to "CamiÃ³n 2.0" instead of "Camión 2.0".
I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `js` file encoding might be different than `UTF-8`, most Probably `ISO-8859-1`. But your `html` page encoding is `UTF-8`.

So Basically `ó` (in `ISO-8859-1`) changes to `Ã³` (in `UTF-8`).

You can try changing your `js` file encoding to `UTF-8`, that should work.

Comment: But in the reference I've already set the encoding UTF-8
`<script src="jscaracteres.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>`
That's right or I have to set the encoding in other place??

Comment: Are you using some IDE for development or just normal text editor.

Comment: Just to be sure you can probably create a new js file and save it with UTF-8 encoding and then try. Keep a backup of old file. If you are using windows, this can probably help to save file in particular encoding - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows

Comment: thank you, I had to open the file .js with nothepad and save with utf-8 encoding and it worked. But It's a bit rare... How can I configure netBeans to do that automatically?

Comment: see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to open the `js` file with notepad and save it with `UTF-8` encoding.

Are there any way to configure NetBeans to do that automatically?