# Java standard input encoding Windows cmd, Netbeans

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, encoding, utf-8

As you will know, [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/InputStreamReader.html) will read the provided `InputStream` and decode its bytes into characters. If no `charset` is specified, it will use the *default charset*.

We can check this *default charset* with `java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().displayName()`.

**Case 1**. My Windows CMD uses [`cp850`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), but Java reports [`windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). It can be proven typing the character `ó` and `System.in.read()` will report `162`, as expected. The `InputStreamReader`, though, will fail to decode it, as it expects to be running `windows-1252`, showing `¢` (this is the 162nd `windows-1252` character).

**Case 2**. In Windows, my Netbeans integrated terminal uses `windows-1252`, but Java reports [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Again, it can be proven typing the character `ó` and `System.in.read()` will report `243`, as expected. The `InputStreamReader`, though, will fail to decode it, as it expects to be running `UTF-8`, showing `�` (code `65533`).

**Case 3**. My Debian machine uses `UTF-8` everywhere, in both GNOME and Netbeans terminals. When typing the character `ó`, `System.in.read()` will report two bytes, `195` and `161`, which correspond to the `UTF-8` representation of that character. The `InputStreamReader` will show `ó` as expected.

**What I want?** Is there a way to correctly detect the *actual* charset used so I can read characters from the command line (in Windows CMD and Netbeans in Windows) without any special case?

Thank you very much.

*The B plan*: Case 2 can be solved by [changing Netbeans file encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans/9085940#9085940) (and it will handle UTF-8 files too, which is what an IDE should do in 2019). Case 1 could be solved by changing the codepage to UTF-8, but I have not been able to make that work.

You may use the following program to test these cases. Enter the same characters twice and compare the output.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Prova2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int b;

        System.out.println("Charset.defaultCharset: " + Charset.defaultCharset().displayName());
        System.out.println("I will read the next bytes: ");
        while ((b = System.in.read()) != '\n') {
            System.out.println("I have read this byte: " + b + " (" + (char) b + ")");
        }
        System.out.println("I will read the next chars: ");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while ((b = br.read()) != '\n') {
            System.out.println("I have read this char: " + b + " (" + (char) b + ")");
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Since `defaultCharset()` returns _"the default charset of this Java virtual machine"_, the way _"to correctly detect the actual charset used"_ would be to explicitly specify that when the JVM starts, but that doesn't seem to be straightforward. There are lots of SO questions on that (e.g. [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/361975/2985643)), but they're old, so it may be worth researching the current situation. Also see old JDK bug [JDK-5052844 : file.encoding parameter ignored on Intel Linux](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5052844).

Comment: Well, yeah, ideally I would that to be detected automatically. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to correctly detect the actual charset used so I can
>   read characters from the command line without any special case?

On Windows you can [detect (or even set) the code page used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54838263/2985643) when reading characters from the command line [using JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). However, that is not necessary if using an alternative approach to obtain the console input:

- Instead of reading from `System.in`, use `System.console` to capture user input. This allows the submitted text to be processed as a `String` rather than `byte`s or `char`s. That provides access to all the `String` methods to interpret the console input as bytes, characters or UTF-8 data.
- With this approach it is crucial to set a suitable code page before submitting input from the command line. For example, if submitting Russian characters then set the code page to 1251 using `chcp 1251`.

Getting user input can be achieved with just two lines of code with this approach:

```
Console console = System.console();
String userInput = console.readLine();
```

> Case 2. In Windows, my Netbeans integrated terminal uses windows-1252...

Don't waste time trying to get console input working in NetBeans. `System.console()` will return null, and its console can't be configured. I suspect that similar limitations exist in other IDEs. Testing within NetBeans provides no meaningful benefits anyway. Just focus on testing from the command line.

> Case 2 can be solved by changing Netbeans file encoding to UTF-8...

Using the approach below, the project's **Encoding** setting doesn't matter. It will work whether the encoding is set to `Windows-1252` or `UTF-8`.

Notes:

- I only tested on Windows but the code should work on other platforms as long as the console environment is set up correctly. (Using `chcp` is specific to Windows as far as I know.)
- Like you, I could not get `chcp 65001` to work for Unicode input. Just focus on ensuring that the input can be read successfully using a suitable code page. For example, when testing with the characters mentioned in the OP (`ó`and `¢`), using any code page supporting those two characters will work. For example: 437, 850, 1252, etc. If the application displays the characters that were submitted correctly then everything will be fine (and vice versa).

Here's the code, which mostly consists of displaying the console input:

```
package prova3;

import java.io.Console;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Prova3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.out.println("System.console() return null.");
            System.out.println("If you are trying to run from within your IDE, use the command line instead.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter some characters...");
        String userInput = console.readLine();
        System.out.println("User input:  " + userInput + " [String length: " + userInput.length() + ", chars: " + userInput.toCharArray().length + ", bytes: " + userInput.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length + "]");
        System.out.println("codepoints:  " + userInput.codePoints().boxed().map(n -> "x" + Integer.toHexString(n) + " (" + n + ")").collect(Collectors.toList()).toString());
        System.out.println("UTF-8 bytes: " + getBytesList(userInput));
    }

    static String getBytesList(String userInput) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder byteList = new StringBuilder("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) {
            byte[] bytes = userInput.substring(i, i + 1).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
                byteList.append(Character.forDigit((bytes[j] >> 4) & 0xF, 16))
                        .append(Character.forDigit((bytes[j] & 0xF), 16));
                if (j < bytes.length - 1) {
                    byteList.append(" ");
                }
            }
            if (i < userInput.length() - 1) {
                byteList.append(", ");
            }
        }
        byteList.append("]");
        return byteList.toString();
    }
}
```

[image: chcp]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, not supporting Netbeans is *not* an option. This is going to be used in class, 1st year, and students struggle too much already by looking at a console inside their IDE. I would not dare to force them to use the CMD every time they need to run their programs.

Comment: @nerestaren OK, I'll take another look. I think it might be helpful to update your question though, to make it clear that the requirement to  _"read characters from the command line without any special case"_ must be done from within NetBeans. (That was not clear to me.)