# Netbeans - Problem with romanian characters (UTF-8), ț and ș are display as?

Tags: php, netbeans, utf-8

This is my netbeans info. I'm writing an website in Romanian and ăîâ work fine, but ț and ș are display as ?.

[image: My netbeans info]

My encoding is set to UTF-8.

[image: Project settings]

Every things works when I use simple text editor like notepad++, the script runs and characters are displayed correctly in the browser.

This is what I see in netbeans.

[image]

I've tried the most popular answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133195/how-to-change-file-encoding-in-netbeans/9085940#9085940) and I've also installed
Encoding Support plugin, but the problem still persist. How can I fix this problem?

[image: Encoding Support]

Comment: Just a shot in the dark... Could it be a font issue?

Comment: Is your source file also in UTF-8? See [UTF-8 All the ways through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170)

Comment: Open the file in an editor where it looks correct. Then save the file again, making sure that you save it as UTF-8 (do _not_ use "UTF-8 with BOM", as that will cause other issues). Then try and open it again and see if it's OK. You should also read the link @RiggsFolly posted.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've checked, it is not a font issue. I've used the same font I use in netbeans in notepad++ and ț,ș are displayed properly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, it is. The weird thing is that if I type ăîâșț in a file using notepad++, they get displayed in netbeans when I open the file, but I can't insert another ș or ț from keyboard, copy and paste the already available ș or ț works.

Comment: That doesn't really prove that point, since editors can potentially replace missing glyphs. Eriksson suggested troubleshooting steps that can help with that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I get your point, you're right. But I use JetBrains Mono and I know it has ăîâșț.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I did what you suggested, they get displayed properly, but I can't add a new ț or ș from keyboard, I can only use copy and paste to add a new ț or ș.

Comment: That suggests some problem with keyboard handling in NetBeans. I know nothing about your language, but those specific characters seem to be problematic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_keyboard_layout

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that this bug was fixed in NetBeans 15.

[image: diacritice]